# Get ID and slug from taxonomy object

Tags: custom-taxonomy, advanced-taxonomy-queries

I have a custom field to select a category (custom taxonomy) and then I will display a list of all of its child-categories. This works fine when I return the custom field as "term_id."

HOWEVER. I would like to also get the slug from this selected category (the parent) so I can link to its category page (I don't think I can link to it with the ID). So I thought maybe I should return the custom field as an object instead. This is what it dumps:

```
 stdClass Object ( [term_id] => 122 [name] => Quick Release Watch Bands [slug] => fits-all [term_group] => 0 [avhec_term_order] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 122 [taxonomy] => product_cat [description] => Watch bands in many colors [parent] => 0 [count] => 293 [meta_id] => 1 [woocommerce_term_id] => 122 [meta_key] => order [meta_value] => 22 )
```

Do you know how I can pull out both the ID (122) and the slug (fits-all) from this? Here is my code so far. The custom field is called "selected_category".

```
<?php $catid = get_sub_field('selected_category');  

            $args = array(
              'taxonomy'     => 'product_cat',
              'orderby'      => 'name',
              'show_count'   => 0,
              'pad_counts'   => 0,
              'hierarchical' => 1,
              'title_li'     => '',
              'depth'        => 1,
              'child_of'     => $catid
            );

            ?> 

<h4><a href="URL.COM/NEED-CATEGORY SLUG"><?php the_sub_field('title'); ?></a></h4>

<ul class="subcats">
<?php wp_list_categories( $args ); ?>
</ul>
```

Can anyone help me, please? Thank you so much!

Comment: This is a Pure PHP question. Look into [basic PHP object syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php).

Comment: Wordpress offers a "get_term_by()" function -- so I wasn't sure if that would be the solution. But I can't seem to figure it out. I will try to see what I can learn from that link. Thank you!

Comment: `$thisisanarray['thisisanarraykey'] = 'this will be its value'`

Comment: $thisisanobject->this_is_a_variable_inside_that_object = "this is now its value"

Comment: Thank you for the help. I think I may have been making this harder than it needed to be. I haven't solved it, but I think I'm going to delete this question and pose it a new way using wp_list_categories to link to the parent too.

Comment: close voted as off topic, this is a basic PHP question, no WordPress knowledge required.

Comment: For those close-voting, I think the person is looking for `get_term_link()` (see my answer). Maybe I totally missed the point of the question, but if my answer's right, I think this is on-topic for WPSE.

Comment: She already has the data she wants, she even dumped it out for us to see, she just doesn't know how to grab the slug part out of the object it gave her so she can use it elsewhere

Comment: @TomJNowell True but there's no reason do go through that when there's a perfectly good WP function to handle the general situation. (It's worth noting that I didn't really answer the question but rather addressed the OP's goal. Your critique of the question is probably right, but I think the answer warrants the question. It's the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for the [`get_term_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_link) function.

Your code will look something like this:

```
<?php
$catid = get_sub_field('selected_category');

$term_link = get_term_link( intval( $catid ), 'product_cat' );
?>

<h4><a href="<?php echo esc_url( $term_link ); ?>"><?php the_sub_field('title'); ?></a></h4>
```

As you can see, `get_term_link()` takes two argument, the term and taxonomy. If you're saving the term object in the field and passing it as the first argument, then the second argument is optional. If you pass the ID, as done above, then you have to pass the taxonomy name.

Comment: YES!! That's exactly what I needed. Thank you so much, mrweb. I really appreciate it.